# How to detect changing variance in a random variable?

Tags: time-series, anova, variance, autocorrelation

Say I have a random variable, and its mean or variance is changing over time, how do I detect this, given back-data? One idea is just to look at the recent values vs the less recent values and detect changes that way? Is there a standardized way to do this? A name for the method?

Comment: In addition to `dglm` mentioned by @GordonSmyth, in `glmmTMB` you can model variation in the dispersion parameter of the response via a separate linear predictor.

Comment: nice thank you that helps for sure

Answer (score 2):

You could consider the dglm package from CRAN, which will do log-linear modelling for the variance at the same time as linear model modelling of the mean.

Here are some references:

**References**

Aitkin, M. (1987). Modelling variance heterogeneity in normal regression using GLIM. Journal of the Royal Statistical Society: Series C (Applied Statistics), 36(3), 332-339.

Smyth, G. K. (1989). Generalized linear models with varying dispersion. Journal of the Royal Statistical Society B 51(1), 47-60.

Rigby, R. A., & Stasinopoulos, M. D. (1995). Mean and dispersion additive models: applications and diagnostics. In Statistical Modelling (pp. 249-256). Springer, New York, NY.